# When I run tests on this componentDidMount in react, apparently several lines are not covered?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to use jest to test my componentDidMount method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    agent.Gatherings.getAll().then((result) => {
        this.setState({ gatherings: result }) //no code coverage
    }).catch((err) => {
        this.setState({ gatherings: [] }) //no code coverage
    })
}
```

yet one of my other tests works fine:

```
  it('test gathering List is rendered', () => {
    wrapper.setState({ gatherings: [TestGathering] })
    expect(wrapper.find('MyList').length).toEqual(1);
  });
```

I want to have every line covered in my testing. How can I get the lines in my componentDidMount() to **all** be tested in jest?

UPDATE, I'm importing a file directly into the test file. The file I'm importing is called agent.js. The code that gets called in the function whose lines are missed are:

`agent.js`

```
export const requests = {
    get: url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()),
    post: (url, body) =>
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: body,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => res.json()) //also this line lacks coverage
}

export const Gatherings = {
    getAll: () =>
        requests.get(API_ROOT + '/gatherings')  
}
export default {
    Gatherings
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue

A line of code has to run *while a test is running* to be included in the `Jest` code coverage.

---

**Details**

The two lines without coverage are the callbacks for the `Promise` returned by `agent.Gatherings.getAll`.

`Promise` callbacks get added to the [PromiseJobs queue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) and run *after the current message completes and before the next message runs*.

This is why those lines are not currently included in the code coverage...*right now they don't run until after your synchronous test completes*.

---

### Solution

You just need to make sure those two lines run *while a test is running*.

---

**Details**

The ideal approach is to [`await` the `Promise` directly in your test](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#async-await).

In this case the `Promise` is not easily accessible from within the test so a different approach is needed.

**Workaround**

If `agent.Gatherings.getAll` is mocked to resolve or reject immediately then the `Promise` callback will be queued in PromiseJobs by the time the component finishes rendering.

To let the `Promise` callback run use an `async` test function and call `await Promise.resolve();` which essentially queues the rest of the test at the end of PromiseJobs and lets any pending jobs run first:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import { Comp } from './code';  // <= import your component here
import * as agent from './agent';

describe('Component', () => {

  let spy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    spy = jest.spyOn(agent.Gatherings, 'getAll');
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    spy.mockRestore();
  })

  it('updates when agent.Gatherings.getAll() resolves', async () => {  // use an async test function
    const response = [ 'gathering 1', 'gathering 2', 'gathering 3' ];
    spy.mockResolvedValue(response);
    const wrapper = shallow(<Comp />);  // render your component
    await Promise.resolve();  // let the callback queued in PromiseJobs run
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ gatherings: response });  // SUCCESS
  });

  it('handles when agent.Gatherings.getAll() rejects', async () => {  // use an async test function
    spy.mockRejectedValue(new Error());
    const wrapper = shallow(<Comp />);  // render your component
    await Promise.resolve();  // let the callback queued in PromiseJobs run
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ gatherings: [] });  // SUCCESS
  });
});
```

You should now have code coverage on the `Promise` callbacks in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: how might the rest of the test look? The mocking?

Comment: how can I mock `agent.Gatherings.getAll` ? I tried setting it equal to `jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce` and it didn't work

Comment: @user11039951 If you add the code that shows how you are importing `agent` into your component module, the module where `agent` is defined, and how you are importing and rendering your component in your test I will update my answer with a more detailed solution.

Comment: so assetion also goes into `setTimeout` and finally it would look like `it('...', done => { expect.assertions(1); const wrapper = ...; setTimeout(() => { expect(wrapper.find('MyList')).toHaveLength(1); done();}, 0);})`. right?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors my post has been updated. Please respond, thanks!

Comment: @user11039951 thanks for the updated code samples.  The way `agent` is written makes it easy to mock and I've updated my answer with a more simple approach.

Comment: @skyboyer yeah, that's the general idea for the `setTimeout` approach.  It turns out that `agent` is pretty easy to mock so just using an `async` test function and calling `await Promise.resolve();` to let the pending `Promise` callback run works just fine.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors thanks for the rest! That being said, I still can't test `.then(res => res.json())` in agent.js